# How to create inline dialog in MS CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

MS CRM 2013 introduced new approach to dialogs opened inside the system. In version 2011 look-ups were opened as separate (modal) windows, but in 2013 look-ups are opened as inline iframes on current page.

Definitely it's possible via following jQuery statements:

```
$('body').append("<div id='InlineDialog_Background' class='ms-crm-InlineDialogBackground' tabindex='0' style='position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); z-index: 1005; opacity: 0.5;'></div>");
$('body').append("<div id='InlineDialog' class='ms-crm-DialogChrome' tabindex='1' style='position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 1006; margin-top: -240px; margin-left: -400px; height: 540px; width: 800px;'><iframe id='InlineDialog_Iframe' name='InlineDialog_Iframe' src='custom_url' style='height: 540px; width: 800px; border: 0px;'></iframe><div id='DialogLoadingDiv' style='position: absolute; background-color: white; height: 480px; width: 800px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -240px; margin-left: -400px; z-index: 1007; display: none;'><table class='ms-crm-LoadingContainer' style='width:100%;height:100%'><tbody><tr class='ms-crm-LoadingContainer'><td style='vertical-align: middle' align='center'><img id='DialogLoadingDivImg' alt='' src='/_imgs/AdvFind/progress.gif'><br>Loading...</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>");
```

But it also requires some additional routines to close such dialog properly.

Is there any Microsoft-provided javascript methods to open such a `iframe`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://mscrmmindfire.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/open-dialog-box-like-crm-2013/) is the example of displaying web resource in such dialog box.

In the parent window:

```
var src = <Relative_Url_of_the_Webresource>;
var DialogOptions = new Xrm.DialogOptions(); 
DialogOptions.width = 500;
DialogOptions.height = 400;
Xrm.Internal.openDialog(src, DialogOptions, null, null, CallbackFunction);

function CallbackFunction(returnValue){ }
```

Also, you have to include *ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx* in your web resource, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webresources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
```

For passing the return value from the dialog box to the parent window:

```
Mscrm.Utilities.setReturnValue(result);
try {
    closeWindow(true); //Close the dialog box
}
catch (e) { }
```

Comment: Looks much cleaner! Thank you!

Comment: When I open a WebResource like this, it appends "?dType=1" to the URL which causes an internal server error as the parameter seems to be invalid (GET http://crm2013/Org/WebResources/tv_closeEmail?dType=1 500 (Internal Server Error) ). Any idea how I can prevent this?

Comment: FYI this worked for reading in dialogArguments window.getInlineDialogArguments()

Comment: Michael Barth -Did you solve the issue in the end we are now having the same on a HTTPS site?

Comment: @Andi: Yeah, actually I found it out just now as I was giving it another try. The thing is, you need to pass the webresource url like this "$webresource:new_yourWebResource" (the prefix "$webresource:" is important!). Then no "dType" parameter will be attached to the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is unsupported and methods are not documented but you can try to use following approach - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2014/05/show-your-dialog-in-crm-2013-modal-style.html

Here is the code:

```
if (typeof Custom == "undefined") {
    Custom = {
        OpenDialog: function (webresource) {
            var $v_0 = new Mscrm.CrmDialog(Mscrm.CrmUri.create(webresource), window, 370, 370, null);
            $v_0.show();
        },
        __namespace: true
    };
}
```

Sample of usage:

```
Custom.OpenDialog("/webresources/new_webresource.htm");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to programmatically open lookup dialogs.

The Dynamics CRM 2013 [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_lookupControlMethods) lists the lookup control methods that are supported:

1. addCustomFilter
2. addCustomView
3. getDefaultView
4. setDefaultView

You can also add presearch events.